# MySQL copy query records to new table field and update current records

Tags: mysql

I'm query the result and I would like to copy `customer_id` to new table field `old_customer_id` and the `customer_id` will replace the latest records.

```
+-------------+-----------------+
| customer_id | old_customer_id |
|-------------+-----------------+
|      5      |                 |
|      3      |                 |
|      1      |                 |
+-------------+-----------------+
```

After my query get the result like above, I would like to copy the `customer_id` to `old_customer_id` which it will

```
+-------------+-----------------+
| customer_id | old_customer_id |
|-------------+-----------------+
|      5      |        5        |
|      5      |        3        |
|      5      |        1        |
+-------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET old_customer_id = customer_id, customer_id = 5
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85b0f/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try two separate `UPDATE` queries. First update the `old_c_id` field then update the `c_id`.

something like:

```
UPDATE customerTable
SET old_c_id = c_id;
```

Then, set the `c_id` in another `UPDATE` query.

**Not sure what would happen if you tried both in the same query though, probably works:**

```
UPDATE cTable
SET old_c_id = c_id, c_id = ??;
```

Comment: How about the `c_id`, I would like to grab the latest `c_id` for replace the rest in table `customer_id` field

Comment: if you want latest, in terms of time, you'd need some sort of date field first. If you mean latest as in the largest number, you could use a sub query in the update: `... c_id = (SELECT MAX(c_id) FROM cTable);`

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE table_name SET old_customer_id = customer_id, customer_id = @your_new_customer_id;